Why does one of the objects not react to the raycaster and the others react in A-Frame?
In the following scene, when with the Oculus Quest 2 with the right hand I direct it to one of the three cubes, the dodecahedron moves: object with the id console-log (It also makes an animation by increasing the size and changing the color). But on the other hand the object with id 5, similar to a book, does not. It seems to react with the raycaster, because the line does not go through it, but the animation of the rotating dodecahedron is not performed.
This is the code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-environment-component@1.3.3/dist/aframe-environment-component.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      AFRAME.registerComponent("color-change-on-point", {
        schema: {
          originalColor: { type: "string", default: "#red" },
          transitionTime: { type: "number", default: 5000 },
          scaleIncrease: { type: "number", default: 1.05 },
        },

        init: function () {
          this.el.setAttribute("color", this.data.originalColor);
          this.isPointing = false;
          this.startTime = null;
          this.hasGrown = false;
          this.originalScale = this.el.object3D.scale.clone();

          // Bind methods to maintain proper 'this' context
          this.onIntersectionStart = this.onIntersectionStart.bind(this);
          this.onIntersectionEnd = this.onIntersectionEnd.bind(this);
          this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);

          // Add event listeners
          this.el.addEventListener(
            "raycaster-intersected",
            this.onIntersectionStart
          );
          this.el.addEventListener(
            "raycaster-intersected-cleared",
            this.onIntersectionEnd
          );
        },

        onIntersectionStart: function () {
          this.isPointing = true;
          this.startTime = Date.now();
          this.hasGrown = false;
        },

        onIntersectionEnd: function () {
          this.isPointing = false;
          this.startTime = null;
          // Return to original color gradually
          this.el.removeAttribute("animation");
          this.el.setAttribute("animation", {
            property: "components.material.material.color",
            type: "color",
            to: this.data.originalColor,
            dur: 1000,
          });
        },

        tick: function () {
          if (!this.isPointing || this.hasGrown) return;
          const entityScene = document.querySelector("a-scene");
          const entityEl = entityScene.querySelector("#console-log");
          entityEl.object3D.rotation.y += THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(-2);

          if (this.startTime) {
            const elapsedTime = Date.now() - this.startTime;

            // Calculate color transition
            if (elapsedTime <= this.data.transitionTime) {
              const progress = elapsedTime / this.data.transitionTime;
              const currentColor = this.lerpColor(
                this.data.originalColor,
                "#FFFFFF",
                progress
              );
              this.el.setAttribute("color", currentColor);
            }

            // After 5 seconds, increase size
            if (elapsedTime >= this.data.transitionTime && !this.hasGrown) {
              this.hasGrown = true;
              this.el.object3D.scale.multiplyScalar(this.data.scaleIncrease);

              // Return to original color
              this.el.setAttribute("animation", {
                property: "components.material.material.color",
                type: "color",
                to: this.data.originalColor,
                dur: 1000,
              });
            }
          }
        },

        // Helper function to interpolate between colors
        lerpColor: function (startColor, endColor, progress) {
          const start = new THREE.Color(startColor);
          const end = new THREE.Color(endColor);

          const r = start.r + (end.r - start.r) * progress;
          const g = start.g + (end.g - start.g) * progress;
          const b = start.b + (end.b - start.b) * progress;

          return `#${new THREE.Color(r, g, b).getHexString()}`;
        },
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-entity
        hand-tracking-controls="hand: right"
        line="color: #FF0000; opacity: 0.5"
      >
        <a-entity
          position="0 0 0"
          raycaster="showLine: true; far: 10; interval: 100; objects: .clickable"
        ></a-entity>
      </a-entity>
      <a-entity hand-tracking-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>

      <!-- Cubos interactivos -->
      <a-box
        class="clickable"
        position="-2 1.5 -3"
        color-change-on-point="originalColor: #FF0000; transitionTime: 1000; scaleIncrease: 1.05"
        animation
      ></a-box>

      <a-box
        class="clickable"
        position="0 1.5 -3"
        color-change-on-point="originalColor: #00FF00; transitionTime: 1000; scaleIncrease: 1.05"
        animation
      ></a-box>

      <a-box
        class="clickable"
        position="2 1.5 -3"
        color-change-on-point="originalColor: #0000FF; transitionTime: 1000; scaleIncrease: 1.05"
        animation
      ></a-box>

      <a-box
        class="clickable"
        position="2 1.5 -3"
        animation
      ></a-box>

      <a-entity
        id="5"
        class="clickable"
        position="-0.35 1.53 -0.5"
        geometry="depth: 0.15; height: 0.24; width: 0.02"
        material="color: #225560"
        animation
      >
      </a-entity>      

      <a-entity
        id="console-log"
        position="-1.49266 2.57466 -5"
        radius="1.25"
        color="#EF2D5E"
        material="color: #2eefa5"
        geometry="primitive: dodecahedron; radius: 0.72"
      ></a-entity>
      <!-- Environment -->
      <a-entity environment="preset: forest; dressingAmount: 1"></a-entity>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>

It can be viewed with the Oculus Quest 2 at https://chipped-stormy-explanation.glitch.me/
